# How to setup Mac OS X Terminal on bash and iTerm2 on zsh

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, zsh, iterm

I attempted to setup bash shell by default on Mac OS X (Yosemite) Terminal app and zsh shell by default on iTerm2 app. However, it is either bash shell or zsh shell for both the apps.

`$ chsh -s /bin/zsh`

sets up a zsh shell for both the apps. While iTerm2 Preferences --> Profiles (Command) option set to `/bin/zsh --login` doesn't load up zsh shell by default for iTerm2 app if bash shell is setup for Terminal app.

Any simple suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user has one shell. A basic environment is setup up when you log in to your computer. $HOME, $LOGNAME, $USER, $TMPDIR, and $SHELL variables are set. Also, the $PATH variable is set to the system PATH. Some of these variables are set by reading info in Apple's version of open directory instead of reading the traditional /etc/passwd. Apple's terminal emulator, Terminal.app, can be set to open another shell instead of your shell set in open directory. Preferences>Startup>Shells open with:>Command radio button>complete path to the shell you wish to run in the text field.

Comment: That seems workable. I was trying the other way around and setting a zsh command in iTerm2 preferences.